# Webform submitForm hook

Tags: 8, webforms

I am using drupal 8 and webform `8.x-5.0-beta25`. I have a multistep form with ajax enabled, 5 pages.

I need to alter the confirmation message but I haven't been able to figure it out. What I want to achieve is change the message depending on some form values the selected on the last question. I've created a custom module and extended the `WebformHandlerBase` and created a `confirmForm` function but I am not seeing anything once the form is submitted.

Again, it is submitting through ajax so I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Here is what I have tried so far

`/modules/custom/cbed_ux/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/QuizWebformHandler.php`

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\cbed_ux\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
/**
 * Form confirm handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 * id = "quiz_handler",
 * label = @Translation("Quiz Handler"),
 * category = @Translation("Quiz Handler"),
 * description = @Translation("Quiz Webform handler."),
 * cardinality = \Drupal\webform\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 * results = \Drupal\webform\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 * )
 */
class QuizWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {
  public function confirmForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    kint($webform_submission);
    drupal_set_message ('submitted!!');
  }
}
```

The form submits, but I do not see my kint or set message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you attach your WebformHandler to your webform via /admin/structure/webform/manage/WEBFORM_ID/handlers?

Your `QuizWebformHandler::submitForm` method does not match the [`WebformHandlerInterface::submitForm`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/Plugin/WebformHandlerInterface.php#n324) definition and should be throwing a fatal exception.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even know that was a thing! I assumed these got picked up regardless. Ok, so when I go to that handlers tab, I am get the WSOD. I did change from submitForm to confirmForm as you see in my edits. My error log is saying `[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant \Drupal\webform\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED`

Comment: nvm, solved it. The namespace changed: https://www.drupal.org/node/2885570. When I click add handler for quiz handler, I am getting a 500 ajax error and it says namepsace has to be the first declaration in QuizWebformHandler.. It is though so not sure what is up

Comment: I have it working now. I must have been looking at old docs because all the namespaces were incorrect for the version I was using. Thank you!